# Windows Server 2016 - MSXML a DOMDocument versions

Tags: domdocument, windows-server, msxml

Which versions of MSXML and DOMDocument are native supported in Windows Server 2012 and Windows Server 2016 after install?

Comment: Sort of pointless.  Version 4 is dead, 5 is part of MS Office.  Versions 3 and 6 should be present or something is very wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Modern versions of Windows come with MSXML3 and MSXML6, by default.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MSXML)

Here's a VBScript to test for the different versions.

```
On Error Resume Next

Tester "MSXML2.DOMDocument.3.0"
Tester "MSXML2.DOMDocument.4.0"
Tester "MSXML2.DOMDocument.5.0"
Tester "MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0"

Sub Tester (ObjectName)
    Err.Clear
    Set obj = CreateObject(ObjectName)
    If Not Err.Number <> 0 Then
        WScript.Echo ObjectName
    End If 
End Sub
```